# How to make `docker-compose up $container_name` to attache not only to $container_name but to all containers it depends on?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I start a specific container with

```
docker-compose up $container_name
```

docker-compose starts this particular container, but attaches the log output for the $container_name only. How I can force it to output all the output for all the containers that $container_name depends on and which are started by the above command? I'd like to see the output of all containers that are started like by

```
docker-compose up
```

but with only the said and dependent containers being run.

Comment: What about running in background (`-d`) and tailing logs of required services using `docker-compose logs -f foo bar`?

Comment: @AliTou probably yes, but I supposed there should be a kind of standard docker-compose option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--attach-dependencies` option:

```
docker-compose up --attach-dependencies foo
```